# Building a Training Classifier Python with NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Currently I'am working on a project which is emotions detecting (happy,sad etc) from text in a chat application using Python and NLTK. I'am not much familiar with NLP and Python. As a basic way, I hope to use keyword based method. In that case I have to make a emotional keyword list under each emotional state and need to find whether there is any emotional keyword in given sentence and identify the relevant emotional state accordingly. So what I need here to know, do I need to create a training data set and feature list to do that task, If yes, how can I do it. Please help me.

Comment: Are you looking for stanford-ner ??

Comment: Not exactly, I want to find the emotional keywords in a given sentence from manually created emotional keyword list.

Comment: I think you can train a set of emotional classes and classify according to it. Here is a Ref : http://text-processing.com/demo/sentiment/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a set of words that have been labeled.  One place to start is the [AFINN](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/publication_details.php?id=6010) sentiment dictionary which is a large set of words that have been manually labeled.  The [slides](https://www.slideshare.net/waitingkuo0527/sentiment-analysisbynltk) by Wei-Ting Kuo shows how to use the AFINN word set.

Laurent Luce's [blog](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/twitter-sentiment-analysis-using-python-and-nltk/) walks through the entire sentiment analysis process using Tweets although he starts with a labeled training set.

[image]

Also take a look at NLTK's 'How To' on [sentiment analysis](http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiment.html)

There are a number of emotion data sets that may help at https://www.w3.org/community/sentiment/wiki/Datasets#Emotions_datasets_by_Media_Core_.40_UFL.

Comment: Thank you. But I do not need to find positive,negative of a given sentence. I want to find the emotional status such as happy, angry and sad.

Comment: The words happy, angry, and sad are in the AFINN data set.  They are rated for valence.  In psychology valence indicates the emotional value that is associated with a stimulus.  The AFINN data set rates each word for a valence with an integer between minus five (negative) and plus five (positive).  Valence is used for sentiment analysis.  You can easily reduce the data set for your more constrained classifications for emotional status.

Comment: Please see my updated answer with a link to other emotion data sets.

Comment: Can you simply explain that how to use the AFINN in my case.

Comment: I have given you a lot of information and references.  I recommend you go through them and try to understand them.  If you can duplicate Laurent Luce's work, and understand it, you will have a much better foundation to solve you problem.